# Windows keyboard layout switcher with "z-order", like Alt-Tab?

Tags: keyboard

Is out there a Windows keyboard layout switcher, which acts like Alt-Tab: recent language on top; pressing a hotkey you switch between two most recent used languages?  Win-Space is nice, but it cycles through all layouts, and such behaviour is inconvenient when more than two layouts installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own keyboard switcher.

The best tool to use may be the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here are a couple of resources containing AutoHotkey scripts that manage
keyboard layouts. You may cannibalize parts of these scripts
to create your final script:

- [Keyboard layout switcher for many layouts](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/70019-keyboard-layout-switcher-for-many-layouts/)
- [Switch keyboard layout on keydown ctrl button](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=68672)
- [Automatic keyboard layout change on window focus using AutoHotkey](https://gist.github.com/christianrondeau/00d7cd5848f33e029f00ce2b6b935ab9)

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I suspected so. :)  Though strange, it's an evident idea: "Alt-Tab mode" is very useful.  Many years I was happy with PuntoSwitcher, where I switched to Russian by hitting right Ctrl, English by left Ctrl, and the other languages with standard Windows hotkey.  But some time ago Skype broke compatibility with PuntoSwitcher, and I look for an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and 11, there is key combination Ctrl-Win-Space, that does something similar: switch between the two last used languages.  Not exactly Z-order, but very useful.